# Refactor model bound controller code to a class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I currently have the code below within my controller.
It looks a little messy here and I'd rather refactor the JQuery into a class.
I will need this database information in a number of places within the site and it seems a shame to not re-use the query.

Is it possible to do this from a class? I'm unsure what object to return it as if the code was within a class.

```
var profileViewModel = (from da in db.table1
                                from ra in db.table2.Where(_ra => da.someID == _ra.someID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                from rg in db.table3.Where(_rg => da.someID2 == _rg.someID2).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                from re in db.table4.Where(_re => da.someID3 == _re.someID3).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                where da.UserName == model.mUserName
                                select new ManageUserAccountsViewModel
                                {
                                    FirstName = ra.FirstName,
                                    Surname = ra.Surname,
                                    Email = da.UserName, 
                               });
```

Comment: In what constructor? If you want to generate your `var profileViewModel` in multiple controllers, you could create a protected method in a BaseController that returns it

Comment: Sorry, I meant controller, I will edit the post now

Answer (score 0):

First, you would want to make your dumb storage POCO. Lets call it that.

```
public class DumbStoragePoco { 
    public string FirstName {get;set;} 
    public string Surname {get;set;} 
    public string Email {get;set;}
}
```

Now we go ahead and create a Data-Access-Layer class for this.

```
public class UserAccountData {
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    public UserAcctionData(DbContext context) { _context = context; }

    public Get(string username) {
        return from da in _context.table1
        from ra in _context.table2.Where(_ra => da.someID == _ra.someID).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from rg in _context.table3.Where(_rg => da.someID2 == _rg.someID2).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from re in _context.table4.Where(_re => da.someID3 == _re.someID3).DefaultIfEmpty()
        where da.UserName == username
        select new DumbStoragePoco
        {
            FirstName = ra.FirstName,
            Surname = ra.Surname,
            Email = da.UserName, 
        });
}
```

You would now instantiate your UserAccountData in your controller, and call the Get method with a username to get an instance of DumbStoragePoco, which you could then pass into any ViewModel you might like. If you want to further the abstraction, you may implement the repository pattern around your data access calls. You could extract an interface from UserAccountData and use that with dependency injection and an inversion of control container to create further abstract to the point where all your Controller does is accept the proper interface in it's constructor, and make it's calls against that for the expected return type.